# Casting To Subtype

Tags: oracle, object, plsql

I've got a base class and another class which inherits from it. Something like the following

```
create or replace type object_base as object
(
    number id,
    member procedure UpdateTable
)
not final
/
create or replace type body object_base is
    member procedure UpdateTable is
    begin
        null;
    end;
end;
/
create or replace type my_object under object_base
(
    overriding member procedure UpdateTable
)
/
create table my_table of my_object;
/
create or replace type body my_object is
    overriding member procedure UpdateTable is
    begin
        update my_table set row = self where id = self.id;
    end;
end;
```

I get the error "ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier" on the line

```
update my_table set row = self where id = self.id;
```

seemingly due to that it recognizes self as object_base rather than my_object. I can't seem to resolve this by using treat(self as my_object). Any solutions?

Comment: That compiled in 11.2.0.4 - at least, with `id number` rather than `number id`. Which version are you using, and when do you see the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your super type which you are ignoring:

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file /tmp/afiedt.buf

  1* create or replace type foo_t as object (number id) not final;
SQL> /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.43
SQL> show errors
Errors for TYPE FOO_T:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/30     PLS-00201: identifier 'ID' must be declared
SQL>
```

Fix this error first. It should be `id number` as pointed out by @AlexPoole.

Comment: You wouldn't end up with an ORA-00904 from that though, you'd get invalid datatype errors first. I assume that's a typo from simplifying the real code ('Something like ...'), but who knows...